# What is the "period" in Fermat's little theorem and why does it divide $p - 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The other posts linked on the closing of this question may seem to indirectly (or somewhere within the answer) provide an explanation. However, they don't answer this specific question at my level. Please note that I am asking 1. the definition of period, and 2. how that divides $p - 1$ *as a direct consequence of Fermat's little theorem.*

---

I found this in [here](https://youtu.be/ao8DY9XS4Hc?t=664), and as it is given, the **period** of the exponential function $f(x) \equiv a^x \pmod p$ divides $p -1$, presumably with $p$ being co-prime to $a \in \mathbb Z$ (?) by Fermat's little theorem.

I see that for an integer $a>0$ and for a prime $p$ the sequence $1,a,a^2, a^3, \dots \mod p$ is periodic, so for instance:

For $a=2$ and $p=7,$ the sequence would be $1,2,4,1,2,4,\dots$, so I presume the **period** is $3,$ which indeed divides $p - 1 = 6$. But I can't find a formal definition for period (tangentially similar to order, but not the same).

Also, by FLT, $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ or equivalently (if $a$ and $p$ are coprime, $a^{p-1}\equiv1 \pmod p.$

But how do I prove that from the above it follows that period $ \mid\  {p-1}$?

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Re: your edit. The definition of the *order* (least period) is aready given in the 2nd dupe, as is the application using Fermat and Euler's theorem. Please read more carefully. Everything that you need (standard arguments) are already in the linked dupes.

Comment: Nothing is being "promoted" by duplication links. There are various answers given in the linked dupes, at various levels of generality, including all of the standard arguments. Again, if you don't understand thee standard arguments then please ask for elaboration in comments. This will help to improve the answers.

Comment: Your result is a special case of Corollary$_1$ in the 2nd linked dupe, viz. by lil Fermat $\,a^{\ell}\equiv 1$ for $\ell = p-1\,$ so $\ell = p-1\,$ is divisible by the order of $\,a,\,$ by the converse direction of the Corollary. The proofs are very simple (one-line of elementary number theory). What is not clear about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the language of group theory, your question concerns the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, the group of units modulo a prime $p$. The "period" of $a^x$ is then simply the order of $a\pmod p$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Now Lagrange's Theorem tells us that the order of an element divides the order of the group. Since the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is $p-1$, we have the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer is vague precisely where I was hoping for help. For instance,  $ord_p(a)$ is the minimum positive integer such that $a^{ord_p(a)} ≡ 1 \pmod p$. The general abstract algebra concept is not wrong.

Comment: Therefore the order of $a$ would not the same as the period.

Comment: Some authors make it precise by saying *least period*. Others define *a period* as any number after which the sequence repeats and *the period* as the *least period*. The order is the least period.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @JAP You can find answers to your questions in the linked threads. If you have questions about any of the answers there then you should post them in comments there  so that the answers can be improved.